# allow submission to controller only after page model is valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model

I have an asp razor page that accepts an email and a password from a sample user. I have defined a set of rules for both of those fields in the page's model. When I click on submit then the values in the form are sent to the controller without the model validating them first. I would like to first check the validation state, highlight errors if any and then allow the server to send the form values to the controller only when there are zero validation errors.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
     
        //define the input fields
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="The email field cannot be empty")]
        [StringLength(10,ErrorMessage ="This email address is too long")] 
        public string Email { get;set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The password field cannot be empty")]
        [StringLength(8, ErrorMessage ="Password needs to ne at least 8 characters")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //show the current page with errors
                return Page();
            }
            //the model state is valid, redirect to Form route
            return RedirectToRoute("Form");
        }
    }
```

HTML markup for the form

```
 <form method="post" id="form" asp-route="Form" onsubmit="return false;">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" asp-for="Email">Email</label>
                    <input name="Email" type="email" asp-for="Email" id="email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" id="es" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" asp-for="Password">Password</label>
                    <input name="Password" asp-for="Password" type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" id="es" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" onclick="check()"class="btn btn-primary" />
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
            </form>
```

_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml

```
<script src="~/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery.js"></script>
```

Declared the ValidationScripts in my Index.cshtml razor page

```
@page
@section Scripts{
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

JavaScript function that serves as a form validation alternative, However I want to use the Model Page validation instead.

```
//define the form as a global

function check() {
    let form = document.getElementById("form");
    let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let es = document.getElementById("es");
    if (email.length == 0) {
        es.innerText = "This field is required";
        return;
    }
    //if there are no errors, submit the form
    form. Submit();
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't your `onSubmit` be set to your `OnPost()` method?

Comment: @Timothy G, I should replace the return false with OnPost?

Comment: Something looks off with it.  I think you can set it to call a javascript function but not code behind.  The javascript function could then invoke your code behind however I think.  What happens right now though when you try to submit?

Comment: @TimothyG, the values in the form are sent to the controller without validation when some such as the password are not even eight characters long

Comment: @TimothyG. It's okay I put return false so I would validate with Javascript but I also read that it's possible to validate with the Code in the model using the field properties

Comment: @TimothyG.should I use asp-action to specify which method in the model should validate the fields?

Comment: What's your check() method ? Could you share your script?

Comment: Note that even if you do have javascript validation, you should still double check on the server action. As any user could mess around with the form submission.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, yes that is why I need to make sure the model does it's job before the form is forwarded to the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to add the `MinimumLength = 8`, if you want to set MinimumLength. Besides you can apply `[BindProperty]` to individual properties to bind posted form values to pageModel properties

   ```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The password field cannot be empty")]
        [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Password needs to ne at least 8 characters", MinimumLength = 8)]
        [BindProperty]
        public string Password { get; set; }
   ```

2.Client-side validation prevents submission until the form is valid. Add below code :

```
@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
```

You can read [Client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-side-validation) to know more.

Result:

[image]

> use the Model Page validation instead.

Try:

```
<form method="post" id="form" >    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" asp-for="Email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="Email" asp-for="Email" id="email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email"id="es"  class="text-danger"></span>
      
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" asp-for="Password">Password</label>
        <input asp-for="Password" name="Password" type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Password" id="es" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" />
    
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying it out in a moment, will accept it of it works

Comment: Where does the code in the answer go? The @section  Scripts

Comment: My check method is a JavaScript function that validates the input field but I want to get used to using the model bindings

Comment: @VibrantWaves    You can add in the html. Or add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>`

Comment: @VibrantWaves  , my code like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe82V.png

Comment: I read the link you attached and learnt that the code in the post should be declared in my index.cshtml file

Comment: Do I declare the unobtrusive js in the ValidationScripts page?

Comment: @VibrantWaves ,what do you  mean ?

Comment: Where do I put this code _@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }_

Comment: Between the page and model tags, got it

Comment: It's not working  the for still gets submitted to the controller with values that do not conform to the rules in the model

Comment: @VibrantWaves , What's your check() method ? Could you share your script? So that we can reproduce your problem .

Comment: Updating the question, check is a JavaScript function that checks for invalid entries and when all entries are clear then it submits the form

Comment: @VibrantWaves  Have a look at my update. Try to remove onclick and   onsubmit="return false;" .

Comment: Thanks I sure hope it will work this time. Thanks.

Comment: It's now throwing a multiple endpoints exception for the request

Comment: @VibrantWaves  Where do you get the error ?Could you share the full error message ?  Do you get the client error as you want ?  Do you excute the OnPost methed ?

Comment: Here is the error and no I do not try to execute onpost from my form, _AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

/Index
/Index
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)_

Comment: @VibrantWaves  "I do not try to execute onpost from my form" what do you mean ?You don't want to submit the form to the OnPost in Index model ?  Besides, How many Index do you have ?

Comment: It worked but after the cookie was reset, now the bindings work and I understand that the model should check first then OnPost Should send the form details to the server but I try checking and tell it to Redirect to Route "Name" where "Name" is Route("api/controller", Name ="Name") with the Code _RedirectToRoute("Name", new {Email, Password} _ but its saying _no route was found with that name_ what could be the problem?

Comment: @VibrantWaves I suggest you try to use RedirectToAction. It's better to create a new post to tell the problem clear about  RedirectToRoute("Name", new {Email, Password} .So that we can reproduce the problem, and also more people can see it and help to solve the problem.

Comment: Do I need _[ActionName]_ before the name of the method in the controller I am trying to call from the model?

Comment: @VibrantWaves You can use `[HttpGet (Name = "aa")]` before your action.

Comment: But why when I am using Post to send the form data to the controller an not get?

Comment: @VibrantWaves  Make sure you have the code in your program.cs :`app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
       pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`  , my result like:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TmaA.gif